# Can't start Play Framework application

Tags: java, playframework

I created  play framework application and unfortunately there is a problem. When I'm trying to execuxe command `activator run` I get:

```
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\playW\app\controllers\Application.java:3: error: package play does not exist
[error] import play.*;
[error] ^
[error] C:\playW\app\controllers\Application.java:4: error: package play.mvc does not exist
[error] import play.mvc.*;
[error] ^
[error] C:\playW\app\controllers\Application.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[error] public class Application extends Controller {
[error]                                  ^
[error]   symbol: class Controller
[error] C:\playW\app\controllers\Application.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
[error]     public static Result index() {
[error]                   ^
[error]   symbol:   class Result
[error]   location: class Application
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ReverseAssets.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature': class file for scala.reflect.ScalaSignature not found
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ReverseApplication.class:
 warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\javascript\ReverseAssets.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature

[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\javascript\ReverseApplication.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ref\ReverseAssets.class: 
   warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\controllers\ref\ReverseApplication.class:
   warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
[error] C:\playW\target\scala-2.11\classes\views\html\index.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'bytes()' in type 'ScalaSignature'
[error] C:\playW\app\controllers\Application.java:11: error: cannot access Html
[error]         return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
[error]                  ^
[error]   class file for play.twirl.api.Html not found
[error] 5 errors
[error] 7 warnings
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -

! @6kd9c54ji - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->'
```

Maybe somebody had this kind of problem because right now I'm stuck.

Comment: It looks like activator hasn't grabbed the play dependency, so: What does your `build.sbt` look like? What about `project/plugins.sbt` ? Have you tried `activator clean`?

Comment: I tried activator 
                 -clean 
                 -run
                 -dependecnies
                 -compile
                 and so one
i think i something in my .ivy2 repository...but i dont know what...
it could be something with my environment cause at work i dont have this kind of problems...i want to build a bussines applisation in this framework but right now im not sure if this is a good path :)

Comment: my build.sbt file:
'**name := """playW"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

scalaVersion := "2.11.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaEbean,
  cache
)**'

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the couse...
The problem leads in my windows 8 account name...I had a polish sign in name so everything was coded not in UTF-8 so this was the reason why I couldn't build my project...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.The issue is latest dependencies or changes are not properly loaded.

Try

```
activator clean cleanFiles compile
```

and then running the application again. Hope that helps.